# PODMAN: Unable to assign IP to a container

Tags: podman

I am testing an application and trying to assign an IP to a container but it kept
on failing with the following messages:

```
# podman create \
   --hostname test1 \
   --name test1 \
   --net test_nw \
   --ip 172.16.1.90 \
   oraclelinux:7
Error: error running container create option: cannot set a static IP if
joining additional CNI networks: invalid argument
```

Following is the network configuration:

```
# cat /etc/cni/net.d/88-racpub-bridge.conflist
{
    "cniVersion": "0.3.0",
    "name": "test_nw",
    "plugins": [
      {
        "type": "bridge",
        "bridge": "cni0",
        "isGateway": true,
        "ipMasq": true,
        "ipam": {
            "type": "host-local",
            "subnet": "172.16.1.0/24",
            "routes": [
                { "dst": "0.0.0.0/0" }
            ]
        }
      },
      {
        "type": "portmap",
        "capabilities": {
          "portMappings": true
        }
      }
    ]
}
```

Comment: I'm struggling with something similar. There's heaps of bugs on github regarding podman and/or CNI not respecting ip and mac options. Have you tried the example provided here: https://blog.carroarmato0.be/2020/05/08/exposing-podman-container-on-the-network/

Comment: This is a known issue with Podman on RHEL 7: https://access.redhat.com/solutions/5369511 What RHEL version are you on?